# Como posicionar dinamicamente uma div com conteúdo dentro de outra criada dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, div, posicionamento

No meu site, crio uma `div` dinamicamente, após o segundo parágrafo (fórum).

Gostaria de posicionar um banner já carregado dentro dessa `div`.

tentei diversas maneiras, dar um `apendchild`, mas não vai.

[Aqui está o URL do site](http://www.retrogamer.com.br/topic/3-regras-do-forum/) para entenderem:

Abaixo o código que estou usando pra criar a `div`:

```
var meupost = document.getElementsByClassName("post entry-content ")[0];
var meudiv = meupost.getElementsByTagName("p")[1];
var meubanner = document.createElement("div");
meubanner.id = "banner300x250-1-auto";
meubanner.setAttribute('class','ipsBox_container');
meubanner.style.height = "250px";
meubanner.style.width = "300px";
//meubanner.style.position = "relative";
meubanner.style.float= "right";
meupost.insertBefore(meubanner, meudiv);
```

Comment: O que você quer colocar lá? Seria o `#google_image_div`? Seria bom também mostrar o que você tentou fazer (e não deu certo), pra gente ver o que está acontecendo de errado.

Comment: P.S. Tentei simplesmente selecionar um elemento qualquer e colocá-lo na `div` criada usando `appendChild` e funcionou normalmente: http://jsfiddle.net/99mshwn8/

Answer (score 1):

Cara, em tempo de execução,  ele não vai adicionar por que na hora que está lendo o DOM, ele não vai achar o elemento que você está identificando para dar o append. 
Para isto funcionar, esta div já deveria estar no DOM na hora que o javascript iniciar a execução.. Dai dinamicamente, preencher a div, e adicionar uma classe que defina os estilos da div.